# Flickr API Key storage

Tags: c#, .net, flickr, api-key

I have a C# application that I want to use [Flickr's API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/).  I received my API key and shared secret, but when receiving the key it explicitly mentions not giving out the API key we were provided.

Since the app is open source and also easily viewed with Reflector, I don't think storing it as a string is really secure.

I could encrypt it with a symmetric key, but that is just obfuscating it since the password for the key will be provided in the code.

My question is, is securing the API Key from Flickr actually necessary?  If so, are there any recommendations for properly securing the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that a random developer's third-party key isn't worth anything. I use a Flickr API Key in my third-party library and simply store it as a string. Flickr's own key to their API would be worth something if dirtied by other use, but someone who wants to get their hands on any API key could look to someone else's open-source project.

Answer (score 2):

I used hashing for this.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? How did you use hashing?

Answer (score 0):

You can see a short discussion on this topic here:

http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7247830